# How to gain a SHA1 fingerprint of certificate for certain application from Play Store?

Tags: android, certificate, fingerprint

I am trying to consider if an android application was wrapped with malicious code by comparing fingerprints of used certificates. I found a way how to retrieve SHA1 fingerprint of certificate at runtime. Now, I would like to retrieve SHA1 finger print of given application from play store. I found some ways how to download .apk (some .apk downloader) and grep this information from enclosed CERT.RSA

```
unzip -p given_app.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA | keytool -printcert | grep SHA1 | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 3 | base64
```

But this way works only for free application. Is there any way how to retrieve fingerprint of every .apk on play store?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not without pirating the software. Also, SHA1 is not especially secure -- please use a better hash, like SHA-256.

Comment: Yep, I know that under some circumstances SHA1 is not collision free.